# getFirstSelectedOption is taking lot of time to return the selected value when dropdown contains huge number of values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

`getFirstSelectedOption` is taking a lot of time to return the selected value when the dropdown has huge number of values.

Please review the code as below:-

```
Select attributeDD = new Select(attributeSelection);            
WebElement attributeWE = attributeDD.getFirstSelectedOption();
```

Is there a method or any technique to get the selected value from drop down with less amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

This will return the HTML `value` of the selected option. I'm not sure if this is something you can use but it might be faster.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(attributeSelection.getAttribute("value"));
```

...and you don't need to cast it to a `Select`.